# Including maven convention folders to classpath in IVY

Tags: ant, ivy

The reason we are using IVY is that we already have ANT scripts. Meaning, there is no maven compatible folders by default.

We had to create such convention.

Now, I already implemented the IVYing. After resolve, I do the

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.test.classpath" conf="test" settingsref="ivy.ref" />
```

The problem with this, it doesn't include the

```
src/test/java , src/test/resources
```

What is the best way of including those.

What I'm currently doing is creating another classpath (postfixed with .extended) that includes the original classpath along with the new folders.

Is there an 'IVYier' way to do it? maybe add something in the dependency file ivy.xml or a way to tell it to act maven.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to add the source dirs to the classpath?

I typically only need to add the compiled classes directory into a classpath and that is typically easier to do directly in the few tasks like Junit that needs to be configured in this manner.

For example:

```
<junit ....>
    <classpath>
        <path refid="runtime.path"/>
        <pathelement path="${classes.dir}"/>
    </classpath>
    ..
</junit>
```

Comment: That's what I meant.
The 'runtime.path' can not include by default the ${classes.dir}?
It was my understanding that in Maven you won't need to even do this.

Comment: @EyadEbrahim There's no way to effectively do this in ANT. Ivy is a dependency manager and does not know where the location of the compiled class files. Maven on the other hand has a standard set of directories, making it easier to make assumptions about how a build works. Finally Maven also provides "out of the box" build logic further dramatically reducing the amount of logic to write.

Comment: I just needed a validation here. Those were exactly my thoughts. Maven is a build tool. IVY is not. I'm thinking to standardize all the projects that I have to the Maven convention (of main/test java/resource) so I could include those in the classpaths consistently. For now, I only do that for projects which have resources directories for example and this is not good software IMVHO.
Thanks again